# Couldn't tap UITableViewCell - margin UI issue in iOS 13

Tags: ios13, swift5, xcode11.3

Similar this

getting issue `UITableVieCell` alignment in iOS 13. Couldn't clickable `tableviewcell`. Action Item text is hidden in top.

[image]

Comment: Please describe your problem with code snippets.

Comment: This is normal UITableviewCell code implemented. cell view incorrectly aligned by left side. But it should be center. Any iOS 13 code changes for tableviewcell?